# How to get access rights to this file?

Tags: windows-11, file-permissions

I'm logged into Windows 11 Pro as Administrator. I still don't have access rights to a MQTT log file `mosquitto.log`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

There are abbreviated instructions what to do at another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597476/enable-log-on-mosquitto-which-is-running-as-a-windows-service-on-windows-server): "1) take ownership with your account, and b) enable inheritance", but after clicking around this dialog, I don't know how to accomplish it.  I would appreciate a no learning curve link or instructions. I'm only an accidental Windows user at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that access rights are not the only thing that can block access; it's also impossible to open a file if another program (such as the Mosquitto server) currently has the same file opened in "exclusive" mode.

> "1) take ownership with your account"

The dialog window shows that the file is already owned by the 'Administrators' group, which should be sufficient.

The "Change" link would allow you to set any owner you want (it actually uses a more powerful operation than even the `takeown` command typically used for this task).

Ownership gives you the right to edit the file's ACL (the access control list under "Permission entries").

> "b) enable inheritance"

Click the "Enable inheritance" button at the bottom. Inheritance will cause Windows to copy all ACL entries from the parent folder's.

Alternatively, you can also click "Add" and manually add yourself to the access list, giving yourself "Full Control" or just "Modify" rights.

Comment: Mosquitto broker is stopped when I try to open the file. "Enable inheritance" was the key. Thank you.

Comment: *manually add yourself to the access list* is the part I don't understand. Who is yourself? *Administrators*?

Comment: Either your own Windows account name, or the "Users" group, or the "Administrators" group (although this might not work due to UAC), or any other group that you're in (such as "Domain Users" or "IT staff"), or even the "Everyone" special label.